# separation of convex cone

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a topological vector space and A a non-empty, closed convex cone in X which is not equal to X. Is there a non-zero continuous linear functional f on X such that f is nonnegative on A? Thank you for any help and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is merely a topological space, there might be no non-zero continuous functional on $X$. The standard example is $X = L^p(0,1)$ with $p \in (0,1)$.

If $X$ is assumed additionally to be locally convex, you assertion should follow from the bipolar theorem.